# HighSTOCKS Exporting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

Can I export a chart (line chart) in Highstocks in ReactJs? If so, how?
The only solutions I can find are of simple highcharts' graphs.

Just to give you an idea attached is the picture of the error I'm getting

[TypeError:.....exportChart() is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptPRE.png)

Comment: Did you import and initialise your export module correctly? 
`import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
HC_exporting(Highcharts);`
Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-mptt9i

Comment: Yes, it is done in this manner

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: In that case, could you please reproduce your issue to the working demo so I could test it?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this. Appreciate all those who helped out.
For Highstocks, you basically do HC_exporting(Highstock).
This was the solution. Thank you!